# my Huawei Modem e303c isnt getting detected in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: huawei

I tried to install the Mobile Partner Linux Edition & the installation did install the NDIS driver. now when the next part comes up of entering the  `pppconfig` , there I’ve set up an AirTel connection and it requires the ISP username and ISP password which I don’t have. so the connection is incomplete. 
now if I enter `lsusb` in the terminal, I don’t find anything related to Huawei modem device. All I find is

```
BUS 001 DEVICE 002: ID 0c45:63f2 Microdia
```

The Device isn't detected after installing the driver too. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am also one of the Modem user. Actually Ubuntu have got smooth way to dealt with Modems. you no need to install Mobile Partner to connect with the internet.
Follow these steps one by one.
Click at your network applet which is at your top panel.
[image]
Select Edit Connections
[image]
In the window choose Mobile Broadband and select Add .
[image]
Then all steps do as I have given there.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After creating the steps successfully you will see a connection at Network applet and selecting that connection will connect your PC to Internet.

Leave the username and password blocks are as empty. all you need to do is simply take care of APN of AirTel nothing but `airtelgprs.com`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What's that theme you're using?

Comment: @Bolt64 MAC Lion theme